# Jquery Input Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I have been searching for a similar question/answer and didn't see one. Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate.

I am creating a text-based game in JS. This is my 1st time creating a project from scratch. All the text happens in the #dialog div and I want to have the user input to correspond to if-else function choices and generate text in the for the new options.

I have the first transition(the text from intro game changes to the text in scene one when clicked)working. What is not working is the choice selection text input. Anything I enter refreshes the game. I also put in an alert to test it and that does not run.

Another question I have is if the variables for the new choices which I have put in the if/else statement will run as coded or if I need to make changes. Some options will occur more than once so I will want it to run from inside multiple scenes.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="dialog">
    </div>
     <div class="form">
      <form id="my-form"> 
       <input type="text" id="userData" placeholder="enter move here">
       <button type="submit" class="btn">play</button>
     </form>
    </div>
```

**JS**
// game dialog box / adds paragraph to the #dialog div
// User move - form input

```
    var addParagraph = $('#dialog');
    var userMove = $("#userData").val();
```

//intro game text

```
    var introGame = $(function () {
       $(addParagraph).append('<p> My Text.. </p>');
    });
```

//1st scene of game. Player chooses 1,2 or 3. Choice triggers new text in dialog box and new set choices or player outcomes.

```
    var scene1 = $(function () {
    $(introGame).click(function() {
    $(addParagraph).text('Move Question Text');
    $(addParagraph).append("<p> 1.Choice Description </p>");
    $(addParagraph).append("<p> 2.Choice Description </p>");
    $(addParagraph).append("<p> 3.Choice Description </p>");
    $(addParagraph).append("<p> Enter: 1, 2, or 3 below </p>");

    var playMove = function() {
      $("#my-form").submit(function() {
        var text = userMove;
        var move = template(text);

    if(text == '') {
       return false;
    } else if(text == '1') {
     $(scene1).click(function () {
       evasiveManuevers();
     });  
    }else if(text == '2') {
      $(scene1).click(function () {
        lightSpeed();
      });
    } else if(text == '3') {
       $(scene1).click(function () {
         fightEnemy();
       });
    } else {
          alert("Working!");
         }    
       });
      };
     });
    });
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Before paste any code, please format it well that is understandable easily.

Comment: I tried to make it easy to understand. I put the code in blocks. What else should I have done? Please forgive this as I am a beginner. Basicall

Comment: Ok thank you for the feedback. I tried to make it easy to understand. I put the code in blocks with a description of what each function is doing or is supposed to do. What else should I have done? Please forgive as I am a total beginner. Basically, the input text form does not work and the if else statement does not run. I am trying to fix these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are doing wrongly is expecting that this

```
var userMove = $("#userData").val();
```

will change during the game. `$("#userData").val()` is a value, not a function, so if I understand what you want correctly, you should create a getter like this

```
var getUserMove = function(){ $("#userData").val(); };
```

and use it as `var text = getUserMove();`. But it's not clear where your

```
var addParagraph = $('#dialog');
var userMove = $("#userData").val();
```

code is (is it inside some handler? I'd recommend to show the whole code as one script, not separate it into some parts).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. I'm wasn't sure what the code looks like to get the input and then use it in my if else statements. Sorry for the confusion, the addParagraph and userMove are both global variables declared at the beginning of the program. The #dialog is where the appended text goes with each move function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your IF statements will run like that. You could do your IF condition testing inside your scene1 click function like this:

```
$(scene1).click(function (){
  if(text == '1') {
     evasiveManuevers();
   } else {
  if(text == '2') {
     lightSpeed();
   } else {
        // etc 
   }

})
```